# Better way to handle speed able time and action in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have came across a problem where i have to do some time based task(simulation) like,
As the game started:

- After 2 mintues launch a missle.
- After 4 mintues star a train on    track
- after 12 minutes start the charater walk etc
  Now i am considering two approaches (other are also welcome)

**Each script manage its time:**

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("MyEvent");
}

private IEnumerator MyEvent()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(120f); // wait two minutes
    //Launch missle etc

}
```

Like this kind of script attach with every object that require action after certain time:
Problem:

1. How do i speed up its time ?
2. Maybe Performance intensive.

**One Timer Global script:**

```
function Update ()
{
Timer += Time.deltaTime; //Time.deltaTime will increase the value with 1 every second.
if (timer>= 120){
//launch missle, an so one conditions
}
```

}

Now using above script i can get Timer variable in other script and can execute my task on based on time. Now the question is that how do i manage it first way or second way or third way(by you)?
Beacause i also want to speedup the time too which seems impossible with coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

### What I would do:

Honestly, the *global approach* doesn't look like the best way to approach this, since it can raise multiple problems: What if I want to update the `waitTime` of a specific object? How do I get a reference to it? What happens if I delete it at runtime? [...] That quickly becomes taxing on performance;

I would honestly create a `Timer` class, which you attach to every object you want to be activated after a certain amount of time (I don't have a compiler at hand, so there might be a couple of errors. Edits are welcome!)

#### Timer

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
     private float m_WaitTime = 1.0f;

     public void WaitTime(float newtime) 
     {
          Deactivate(); // deactivate the object
          StopCoroutine(Wait()); // stop the coroutine
          m_WaitTime = newtime; // update the time 
          StartCoroutine(Wait()); // wait for "newtime" seconds
     }

     private IENumerator Wait()
     {
         // wait until the wait time is 0
         while (m_WaitTime > 0.0f)
         {
             // decrease the wait time on every iteration of this loop
             m_WaitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
             yield return null;
         }
         // finally, activate the object
         Activate();
     }

     private void Activate()
     {
          Debug.Log("Object Activated");
     }

     private void Deactivate()
     {
          Debug.Log("Object Deactivated");
     }
}
```

This way we can have multiple *self-managed* entities, that don't rely on a global object and that can be added, removed or updated without causing any issues.

You could even make an abstract class and implement different types of behaviours, or maybe use an enum and change the object's behaviour based on it's value ;)